# Overlay an InkCanvas on a custom WinForms control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, inkcanvas

I have a custom WinForms control that displays some graphics. I need to overlay an `InkCanvas` on top of this control. The `InkCanvas` should be "see through" (transparent background, visible ink). This `InkCanvas` allows the user to sketch on the graphics being displayed.

I know about the airspace issue in WPF/WinForms interop (the fact that WinForms elements hosted in a WPF window will always stay on top of all other components). So obviously I cannot achieve the desired effects in WPF. I decided to go about the problem the other way around (host an `InkCanvas` in a WinForms form and overlay the `InkCanvas` on my custom control).

The problem is that the WinForms `ElementHost` cannot be made "see through" (no transparency can be set). I tried deriving ElementHost with the following override

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

But this will make the whole thing completely transparent (the sketches are not visible any more).

How can I have the "see through" `InkCanvas` with visible ink overlayed on the WinForms control?

Comment: I don't think you can do this due to the "airspace" problem.  Here's a resource on the subject, not sure if it applies completely to your problem... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2013/02/26/mitigating-airspace-issues-in-wpf-applications.aspx

Comment: ElementHost *creates* an "airspace", it cannot remove one.  Only way ahead is to layer another transparent borderless window on top of the one you have.

Comment: Thank you both. I see... If that's the case, then I will consider creating my own InkCanvas in the graphics viewer user control...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and lack of answers, we can safely assume that what I want to do is impossible unless we do the "window layering" hack that @Hans Passant mentioned.